# Como colocar margen a las filas con Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, grid

Un gran saludo:

La situación que deseo plantear es la siguiente, sucede que tengo una sección que va en una fila (row) es un texto que deseo quede en el centro de la fila verticalmente,entonces cree un Div con un nombre y le coloque propiedad de margin top, en la versión pantalla se ve bien, pero cuando se reduce hasta llegar a una versión móvil, todo ese margin hace que el contenido se corra hacia abajo, y ese margin no se ajusta.

En este caso no sé si esa propiedad es la apropiada o existe otra manera de hacerlo.

Así se ve cuando esta en la visión de computador normal.
[image: Así se coloca cuando esta en resoluciones más pequeñas]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código que tienes actualmente? De esta manera te podremos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas trabajando BootsTrap supongo que debes saber que cada **ROW** trabaja con 12 **Columnas** llamemoslo asi, y esto nos permite hacer que cada elemento en su `class` ocupe determinado espacio segun el tamaño de las pantallas en donde se visualice.

Para eso solo agrega esto al `class` del contenedor en donde se encuentra el texto :

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
             //En este caso utilizo un `article`

       </article>

col-xs-12 -->Indica que en pantallas super pequeñas abarque todas las 12 columnas, osea el 100%. Este es el que deberias aplicar a tu contenedor.

col-sm = Pantallas pequeñas
col-md = Pantallas medianas
col-lg = Pantallas grandes
```

Puedes visitar este curso de FalconMasters en donde explica muy bien como funciona BootsTrap https://youtu.be/nug1pMke-y4